# JList horizontal auto-scroll to right

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jlist

I have a jlist that contains items written in arabic, and unfortunately if any item is long, all items disappear after loading, because the scroller doesn't autmaticly scroll to right, and I should manualy scroll the list horizontaly to right.

I have set the JList's componentOrientation to right.

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal working example and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JList is in a JScrollPane, you can set the value of the horizontal scroll bar:

```
final int maximum = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(maximum);
```

Like in the example here:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList horizontal auto-scroll to right");
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 80, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
final String[] model = {"aaa", "bbbb", "ccccccccccccccccccccccccc"};
final JList<String> jList = new JList<String>(model);
jList.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
final int maximum = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum();
scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(maximum);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

For me, the window looks like this:

[screenshot frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72fR.jpg)

Comment: Yes, the JList is within a JScrollPane. And even I add `setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` the jlist doesn't scroll autmaticaly to right.

Comment: Yes, that's strange. Maybe because the JScrollPane doesn't check the component orientation of the JList? Is it possible for your application to scroll programatically?

Comment: I think that the `setComponentOrientation` has nothing to do with the scroller, because its main role is to set text orientation from right to left. concerning your last qt, this is what I'm looking for, scroll programaticaly to right.

Comment: You can programatically scroll to the right by calling scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(maximum).

Comment: That's frustrating. Did you try my example code? What is the value of scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum() for you? Can you post your code?

Comment: Try scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(minimum);

Comment: Now is working, thank you! the problem is that I'm using `setViewportView` to add the list to the scrollpane, and when I put your code before `setViewportView`, it has no effect, otherwise when I have moved your code at the end it works.